# Vaadin's SplitLayout.setSplitterPosition(80) only works the first time; subsequent calls do not seem to respond

Tags: vaadin, vaadin12

In Vaadin 12, I have created a button which, when clicked, sets the split layout position to some non-zero, non-100 value, as shown below:

```
  btnHelp.addClickListener(event -> {
            log.info("info pressed");
            MainApp.sp.setSplitterPosition(80);
            MainApp.iFrameHelp = new Html(          "<iframe src=\"https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html\"></iframe>");
            //btnHelp.setIcon(new Icon(VaadinIcon.INFO_CIRCLE));
        });
```

This works great. However, if I pretend to be a user and, via the Chrome browser, I adjust the split layout (by dragging the vertical layout) such that I "close" (or just reduce the size of) the second vertical "panel", and *THEN* I click on the button again, it does NOT seem to obey the command to reset the splitter position to 80. It only seems to obey the command on the first call. Is this a bug? If so, is there a workaround? (Or, should I do this differently?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a side effect of https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-split-layout-flow/issues/50. What happens is basically that the server-side still believes that the split position is set to 80 which makes it ignore the `setSplitterPosition(80)` call.

You can work around this by using low-level APIs to set the position in a way that bypasses the server's dirty checking logic:

```
MainApp.sp.getPrimaryComponent().getElement().executeJavaScript(
    "this.style.flexBasis='80%'");
MainApp.sp.getSecondaryComponent().getElement().executeJavaScript(
    "this.style.flexBasis='20%'");
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried your code exactly as described, and it didn't refresh the screen after I clicked on the button a second time....Is there a "refresh" command that I am supposed to send?

Comment: Also, the link you mentioned (for issue 50) seems unrelated, but I'm not sure....

Comment: Based on your (very) helpful background explanation, I came up with an (ugly but working!) hack! I simply call "MainApp.sp.setSplitterPosition(f); f++;" such that f is always a different number that what it was set to previously. This seems to trick Vaadin into refreshing the screen. Thoughts?

Comment: So, maybe I spoke too soon. My explanation above was probably true for Vaadin 12; for Vaadin 13 beta1 pre-release, *neither* my trick above nor your suggestion of executing the javascript command worked on the *second* click...Not sure why....

Comment: My hack does indeed not work. But it seems like it works if you change the JS expressions to set `this.style.flexBasis` instead. I'll update my answer to show this.